# Can I decrypt password using the private key generated in Django backend in Flutter?

Tags: django, flutter, dart, encryption, cryptography

I am making a password manager app where I am using asymmetric encryption to store passwords. I have created a Django backend for the app where I have stored the user's public key in the User model. During registration, I am storing the public key in the database and sending the user their private key to the Flutter app.

I am using the following function to encrypt the password and store it in the password store model:

```
def encrypt(data, key):
    key = serialization.load_pem_public_key(
        key.encode(),
        backend=default_backend()
    )

    data = key.encrypt(
        data.encode(),
        padding.OAEP(
            mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
            label=None
        )
    )

    return data
```

Now, I want to know if I can decrypt passwords or any other string data in Flutter using the private key that is generated in the Django backend. If yes, how can I do it?

Also, I don't want to pass the decrypted password from the backend to the Flutter app. I want the client-side to handle it. For this, I am storing the private key in the user's device using shared preferences in Flutter:

```
SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
    prefs.setString("privateKey", widget.privateKey);
});
```

Can anyone help me with this?

I tried using the decryptByPrivateKey function below to decrypt a password on the client side in my Flutter app using a private key generated on my Django backend:

```
dynamic decryptByPrivateKey(String content) async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final private = prefs.getString('privateKey')!;

  RSAKeyParser parser = RSAKeyParser();
  RSAPrivateKey privateKey = parser.parse(private) as RSAPrivateKey;
  AsymmetricBlockCipher cipher = PKCS1Encoding(RSAEngine());
  cipher..init(false, PrivateKeyParameter<RSAPrivateKey>(privateKey));
  return utf8.decode(cipher.process(Encrypted.fromBase64(content).bytes));
}
```

However, I got the following error related to the content parameter, and I'm not sure how to resolve it:

`FormatException: Invalid character (at character 2) b'\rV\x86ldn\x171*^c\xabsAc;\xead\xea\x05C\x996o\x0e@\xe2\xed\x1c\xa21\x80d... ^`

Also, I am generating and sending the private key to the client as shown in the code snippet below:

```
private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537,
    key_size=2048,
    backend=default_backend()
)

public_key = private_key.public_key()

public_key = public_key.public_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
)

private_key = private_key.private_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
    encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
)

private_key = private_key.decode('utf-8')
public_key = public_key.decode('utf-8')
```

I am hoping to be able to decrypt the password on the client side using the private key without passing the decrypted password from the backend. Can anyone help me with this issue?"

Comment: The codes seem to use different paddings: RSA with OAEP/SHA-256 in the Python/Cryptography code, RSA with PKCS#1 v1.5 in the Dart/PointyCastle code.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am not aware if we have the same OAEP/SHA-256 in PointyCastle or not.

Comment: It does - see: `factory OAEPEncoding.withSHA256` documented here: https://pub.dev/documentation/pointycastle/latest/impl.asymmetric_block_cipher.oeap/OAEPEncoding-class.html

Comment: "I am [...] sending the user their private key." Don't do that. Generate the key pair on the client and submit the public key (if that's even necessary; the server shouldn't have any use for it, typically. Why did you choose asymmetric encryption to begin with?). The server should never ever see the encryption key.

Comment: Thanks @RichardHeap for your response, I will have a look at it. 

Yes, Peter you are right I shouldn't generate the private key from the server but rather user should generate that, but given, this is my 2nd flutter project, I didn't want to do the heavy lifting in a flutter. Also, the whole reason I am making this project is to learn asymmetric encryption, and how to encrypt/decrypt data between different languages & ends. Anyways thanks for your time.